# General rule for tag parameters dynamic changes

Tags: javascript, dynamic

Just found that changing href dynamically can be implemented differently and one method with

```
 document.anchors[] =
```

works for FireFox and Chrome and does not for IE while using

```
 document.getElementById(..).setAttribute('href',
```

works for All.
Is there a general rule for such changes that one can take for granted or is it always tag/param specific?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Works for all.

**EDIT:**

A precise detail can be read from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)

How you can use it to get all the hyperlinks (anchors) of the page (or frames - depend on the `window` object context):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var index=0; index<links.length; index++) {
// links[index].href = links[index].href + (links[index].href.indexOf("?") ? "&" : "?") + "hello";
}
```